# получить список статусов заказов с платформы Prom.ua

Tags: python

пытаюсь получить список статусов чтоб использовать для фильтров при отборе но выкидывает ошибку
https://my.prom.ua/api/v1/order_status_options/list
Ошибка при запросе к API: 403

```
url = "https://my.prom.ua/api/v1/order_status_options/list"
headers = {
"Accept": "application/json",
"Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}"
 }

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```